# Prove $X - \bigcup_{C \in \scr{C}}C = \bigcap_{C \in \scr{C}}(X - C).$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove $X - \bigcup_{C \in \scr{C}}C = \bigcap_{C \in \scr{C}}(X - C).$

*Proof*. Assume $a \in X - \bigcup_{C \in \scr{C}}C$.

Then $a \in X$ and $a \not\in \bigcup_{C \in \scr{C}}C$.

Then $a \in X$ and $a \not\in \bigcap_{C \in \scr{C}}C$, since for all $C \in \scr{C}$ we have $a \not\in C$.

I don't think I am going the right path here. How do I continue?

Comment: Keywords: DeMorgan Law. This was asked at least uncountably many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints to get you going again.

To complete this direction, we have to prove that $a \in \bigcap\limits_{C \in\mathscr C} (X-C)$. By definition of intersection, this amounts to proving $a \in X -C$ for every $C \in \mathscr C$. It may be helpful to look at the definition of union, and think about what it means *not* to be an element of it.

For the converse direction, if $a \in X-C$ for every $C \in \mathscr C$, we need to prove $a \in X$ and $a \notin \bigcup\limits_{C \in\mathscr C} C$.

I'm confident you can handle it from here.

Comment: For the first direction, I continued with, 

Thus $a \in (X - C)$ for every $c \in \scr{C}$. Thus $a \in \bigcap_{c \in \scr{C}}(X-C)$. Correct? @Lord_Farin

Comment: It depends; are you yourself comfortable with the step "$a \notin \bigcup_{C \in\mathscr C} C$" $\leadsto$ "$a \in (X-C)$ for every $C \in \mathscr C$"? I suggest you expand on this step, by adding one or two intermediate steps (e.g. unfolding the definition of union, describing an appropriate equivalent of "not being an element of the union"). You're welcome in the [Mathematics chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) to discuss it further.